# ftp_put() working sometimes but most of the time doesn't

Tags: php, ftp

I'm developing a web application with PHP, to upload files to a web server which merges, compresses those files (pdf) and then upload the new files to another FTP server. This second ftp server is used as a network driver in my offices so people can work with uploaded files.

The number of files goes from 2 to 7 for one upload.

I'm having the following problem: Sometimes files are uploaded, but most of the time they aren't. Sometimes one file on three is uploaded and the two others are not.
I almost always get this:

*Warning: ftp_nb_put(): The connection timed out in ...*

*Warning: ftp_nb_put(): Opening data channel for uploading files to server from...*

*Warning: ftp_nb_put(): File not found in...*

I tested with another (personal) FTP server from a webhost and it worked perfectly 10/10 times.
So I guess that the problem is coming from the ftp server.

I also tested with passive mode, but I get more error, even with :

```
ftp_pasv($ftp, true);
ftp_set_option($ftpconn, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false);
```

I don't have access to the FTP server settings, so I would like to know what could possibly be blocking downloads to give information to the service that manages this.

This is my code, for the FTP part :

```
$ftp = ftp_connect($ftp_hostname, 21);
ftp_login($ftp, $ftp_username, $ftp_password);

ftp_mkdir($ftp, $targetdir);

foreach($file as $filename => $path) {
    if(file_exists($path)) {
        $upload = ftp_nb_put($ftp, $targetdir.$filename, $path, FTP_BINARY, FTP_AUTORESUME);    
        while (FTP_MOREDATA == $upload){
            $upload = ftp_nb_continue($ftp);
        }
        if ($upload != FTP_FINISHED) {
           echo "Error with : ".$path;
        }
    }
    else {
        echo("File not found : ".$path);
    }
}
ftp_close($ftp);
```

I hope I didn't miss any information,

Thanks !

Comment: Please try  with the synchronous ftp_put function to see if that fixes the issue.    https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Comment: Already tried it before, but I just gave it a new try and still the same errors...

Comment: I have the same error, can you please share your solution (if you have one since then)?